# 2D Array of pointers to structs. Memory access issue

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a program to compute the Hungarian method for a set of Jobs:Workers.
I know how I am going to code the bulk of the program, but I am stuck at loading my matrix.
I have created a class to store info in, and I have created a 2d array of pointers to objects of this class. Each entry of the matrix should hold a cost value assigned to that Worker:Job combo.

Every time I try to load the costs into the objects within the array, I keep getting a memory access violation, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Chris

```
using namespace std;



class costPtr{
    int cost;
    int fillRow;
    int fillColumn;

public:
    costPtr()
    {
        int fillRow = 0;
        int fillColumn = 0;
        cost = 0;
    }

    void fillCost(int costInput)
    {
        cost = costInput;
    }

    int printCost() const
    {
        return cost;
    }
};


void fillMatrix(costPtr*** matrix, int workers, int jobs);

void methodMain();

void printMatrix(costPtr*** matrix, int workers, int jobs);



int main()
{
    methodMain();
}

void methodMain()
{
    int jobs, workers;
    cout << "How many jobs are there:   ";
    cin >> jobs;
    cout << "How many workers are there:   ";
    cin >> workers;

    costPtr*** matrix = new costPtr**[workers];

    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
        matrix[i] = new costPtr*[jobs];

    fillMatrix(matrix, workers, jobs);

    printMatrix(matrix, workers, jobs);
}

void fillMatrix(costPtr*** matrix, int workers, int jobs)
{
    int cost;

    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < jobs; j++)
        {
            cout << "What is the cost for worker " << i + 1 << " doing job " << j + 1 << ":   ";
            cin >> cost;
            (matrix[i][j])->fillCost(cost);
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(costPtr*** matrix, int workers, int jobs)
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < jobs; j++)
            cout << (matrix[i][j])->printCost() << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).  Use containers, abstractions and references to make life easy.

Comment: Without seeing the code that populates the matrix, there is no way for anyone to find the error. From what you have posted, seeing `costPtr***` as the type of the first parameter seems incorrect to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I had no idea such a term as 'three star programmer' existed :). Well put and posted.

Comment: I have only been learning C++ for a few months, and arrays of pointers still give me trouble. I don't have a lot of experience yet with too many libraries.
I just wanted to make a 2d array of pointers to objects, and from what I looked up in other threads on this site, i thought using *** was a good option. Please correct me if there is a better way. I am always looking to learn more.
Also, Andy, the code to fill it is in the block, the part at the top is just the function prototype.

Comment: if i didnt miss something you never actually create instances of  `costPtr`. I would suggest that you forget about pointers completely for now and take a look at `std::vector` and/or `std::array` instead

Comment: i am learning c++ for more than a decade and pointers still give me trouble, thats why I just dont use them unless I need to ;). The thing is that you really dont need them that often

Comment: The reason I used pointers was because, since I wanted the user to specify the size, I needed to use a dynamically allocated array.
I suppose I could have used a vector, but I chose array out of habit. Usually when I do multidimensional matrices, arrays just fell less tedious to me, but then again I usually haven't needed to do run-time allocation when I've used them.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a dynamically sized array

Comment: @NathanOliver Some say the higher level of one's pointer abstraction directly affects one's well-endowment in one's nether region.

Comment: @DeiDei The pointier you are the better? ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver We are in fact talking about levels of pointiness here. It is the girthiness that is under advisement here in our quite righteously named sophisticated conversation. I apologize, I might be a raving alcoholic...

Comment: at least the discussion isnt point(er)less

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be a "2d" matrix, it should be `costPtr** matrix`.

```
// An array of pointers
costPtr** matrix = new costPtr*[workers];

// Each element in the array is (a pointer to) another array
for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
    matrix[i] = new costPtr[jobs];
```

Of course, there are always the standard containers like `std::vector`. You can have a vector of vectors:

```
// Create and initialize a workers x jobs matrix
std::vector<std::vector<costPtr>> matrix(workers, vector<costPtr>(jobs));
matrix[2][3].printCost(); // Example usage
```

No explicit memory allocations or pointers.

---

Edit: After re-reading I see you wanted a "2d array of pointers" so `costPtr*** matrix` is correct, but you need one more step:

```
costPtr*** matrix = new costPtr**[workers];
for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new costPtr*[jobs];
    for (int j = 0; j < jobs; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = new costPtr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The specific cause of the error is here:

```
(matrix[i][j])->fillCost(cost);
```

You have declared the pointer, but then you give a command to the object that the pointer points to-- which does not exist. You never constructed it.

The deeper problem is that you attempted this with an array of arrays of pointers, before you tried it with a pointer. When you write code, you should start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. (For some reason, this rule never comes up in programming courses.)

Comment: i once had a c++ teacher who insisted on a "write one line - compile" cycle. Students were making fun of him, but he was right.

Comment: So what would be the proper way to construct it in this circumstance, then?
I have gotten this code to work now, using a vector, but I would still really like to better understand the pointer issue.
I usually have no trouble understanding anything, so when I come across something like this, I get really frustrated.

Comment: @Chris: You can start with `Thing *ptr = new Thing;` and `Thing *ThingArray = new Thing[5];`. Be aware that an array of `Thing` is not an array of `Thing*`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't even think to construct the matrix with an inside out approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the dynamic allocation of you matrix container. To reach your goal, every "star" in the container type must have a "new".

You successfully dealt with the first 2 pointers, like so:

```
costPtr*** matrix = new costPtr**[workers];

for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
    matrix[i] = new costPtr*[jobs];
```

Now all you need to do is deal with the third pointer:

```
for (int i =0; i < workers; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < jobs; j++)
    matrix [i][j] = new costPtr;
```

Without the last pointer allocation, all elements would point to a `null`.